# Property depending on property from another class

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, inotifypropertychanged, fody-propertychanged

I've got a Windows Phone 8 application using Fody to inject INotifyPropertyChanged into properties.
I have Class First with property A which is binded to textbox in View:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class First
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public int AA { get {return A + 1; } }
}
```

And class Second with property B depending on property A (also binded to textbox):

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Second
{
    private First first;

    public int B { get {return first.A + 1; } }
}
```

Updating A and AA works fine, however B doesn't update automatically when first.A changes. Is there an easy and clean way to achieve such automatical updates using fody or do I have to create my own event to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using standard INotifyPropertyChanged in the way SKall suggested.

```
public class First : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public int AA { get {return A + 1; } }

    (...) // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}

public class Second : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private First first;

    public Second(First first)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.first.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => { FirstPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);

        public int B { get {return first.A + 1; } }

        protected virtual void FirstPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (propertyName == "A")
                NotifyPropertyChanged("B");
        }

        (...) // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Fody but I suspect it is because there is no setter on Second.B. Second should subscribe to changes in First and if First.A is the property being changed then that should use the (private) setter of B.

Alternatively subscribe to First and then invoke B property changed event:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Second
{
    private First first;

    public int B { get {return first.A + 1; } }

    public Second(First first)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.first.OnPropertyChanged += (s,e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "A") this.OnPropertyChanged("B");
        }
}
```

Comment: Setter is not requiered to update the view. I added property AA in First which will update just fine when A changes.
What I'm asking for is Fody functionality to avoid creating manual subscribtions in Second.

Comment: Actually looking at Fody it is required. In the case of being inside the owning class it is just automatically injected into the code: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: I've seen that earlier, however, that doesn't solve my problem.
Of course, i could add an event and handle it in Second by setting B with a private setter to force an update, but unfortunetelly that solution is not scaleable.

Comment: It does seem though Fody isn't your magic bullet as it will only inject the code in the owning class. Have you looked into ReactiveUI? It might offer something more elegant (but still somewhat manual).

Comment: According to your edit: it is not possible to use OnPropertyChanged event in class with [ImplementPropertyChanged] attribute.
Maybe indeed Fody does not provide solution for my problem, however it seems that there still can be a simple way around similar to one you provided.

Comment: Is that a compile error? I would assume since it's injected code. I would think RxUI would give you better tools to accomplish what you're after. http://www.reactiveui.net/

Comment: It's compiler error [CS1061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CS1061)) to be specific. I'll give RxUI a try, thx for the suggestion.